# Raster files displayed in QGIS without black background

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, google-colab

I have .tif images which I can see with the black background in Windows Photo Viewer like this:

[image]

However, when I displayed it in QGIS, rectangular shape of the image is gone and it is shown like this:

[image]

How can I eliminate this problem?

Comment: It is not a problem but a feature. Black is marked as nodata into your image, which means that QGIS considers those pixels non-existing and renders them transparent. You can turn off the transparency from the layer properties - Transparency - No Data Value.